# Installing symbolic or any package with euler function in octave

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, directory

Need help installing symbolic, or any package that can allow me to use the Euler function.  I tried this on my CMD

```
sudo apt-get install octave-symbolic
```

but when I load it in octave, I have this warning:

```
warning: the 'euler' function belongs to the symbolic package from 
Octave Forge but has not yet been implemented.

Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
warning: called from
__unimplemented__ at line 524 column 5
euler12 at line 28 column 15
error: 'euler' undefined near line 28 column 16
error: called from
euler12 at line 28 column 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the function was not available when the question was asked, now it has been implemented. To install it, first uninstall the Ubuntu package (which is stuck in the old version), and replace it with the new version from octave-forge.

```
sudo apt remove octave-symbolic
```

Now open Octave, and enter the command

```
pkg install symbolic
```

It will take some time.

Once installed, use `pkg load symbolic` to use the `euler` function. You can add `pkg load symbolic` to `.octaverc`, so that this package is loaded at Octave startup.